# COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci getting removed from schema.rb after migrate

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Running rails 5.0.2

The tables in our schema.rb in source control seem to mostly have the format:

```
create_table "app_files", 
    force: :cascade, 
    options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci" 
do |t|
```

Note the `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci"` at the end.

When I run migrations the generated `schemaa.rb` is mostly the same but chops off `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci"` from those lines so it now looks like:

```
create_table "app_files", 
    force: :cascade, 
    options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" 
do |t|
```

Based on other SO posts I've tried two things to fix this

1) in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I added:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server  = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

2) in my `database.yml` ive added `collation: utf8_general_ci` to all of the relevant environments

I then restarted mysql, dropped, created and migrated my db but still the collate line disappears.

Any thoughts on what configuration I need to change to have that bit autogenerated ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch unfortunately not

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, and resolved it by adding `encoding` and `collation` settings into my `database.yml` config file.

I wonder if yours are being ignored because they're the MySQL defaults. You should try using `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, with the added benefit that they support 4-byte characters such as certain emoji characters.

Here's the `default` section of my `database.yml` file for reference:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is removed because it's the default. I could find a [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html) in the MySQL docs that says:

> For example, the default collations for latin1 and utf8 are latin1_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci, respectively.

So having `CHARSET=utf8` already implies `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` unless otherwise specified.

So it is safe to commit this change.